# How to get the number of elements (variants) in an enum as a constant value?

Tags: enums, rust

Is there a way to extract the number of elements in an enum?

Simple example (with imaginary `number_of_elements` method):

```
enum FooBar { A = 0, B, C, };

println!("Number of items: {}", FooBar.number_of_elements());
// "Number of items: 3"
```

In C I'd normally do...

```
enum FooBar { A = 0, B, C, };
#define FOOBAR_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS (C + 1)
```

However the Rust equivalent to this doesn't work:

```
enum FooBar { A = 0, B, C, };
const FOOBAR_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS: usize = (C as usize) + 1;

// Raises an error:
//     unimplemented constant expression: enum variants
```

Including the last item in the enum is very inconvenient because matching enums will error if all members aren't accounted for.

```
enum FooBar { A = 0, B, C, FOOBAR_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS, };
```

Is there a way to get the number of items in an enum as a constant value?

---

Note: even though this isn't directly related to the question, the reason I was wanting this feature is I'm using the [builder-pattern](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/builder.md) to construct a series of actions which only make sense to run once. For this reason I can use a fixed size array the size of the enum.

Comment: I agree that this a feature which would be useful. Just out of interest: why do you need the number of variants?

Comment: Added explanation of why I was looking for this feature.

Comment: To be honest, I find it inconvenient in C and C++ too because then I have to handle the cases in my `switch` which pollutes my code. In C and C++ I cheat with using a macro for declaring enums (black wizardry...) which also declare a few alternate things including this size which is so useful. I guess a macro would work in Rust too... but I am hoping for something better... (a custom derive could probably do the trick too, I guess...)

Comment: Agree, at least in C/C++ you can use the last element to declare a constant outside the enum, but visually close - so developers adding new members aren't so likely to forget to update it (added example).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update as of 2022

There's a new function [std::mem::variant_count](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.variant_count.html) in **rust nightly** version.

Example to use by [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.variant_count.html).

```rs
use std::mem;

enum Void {}
enum Foo { A(&'static str), B(i32), C(i32) }

assert_eq!(mem::variant_count::<Void>(), 0);
assert_eq!(mem::variant_count::<Foo>(), 3);

assert_eq!(mem::variant_count::<Option<!>>(), 2);
assert_eq!(mem::variant_count::<Result<!, !>>(), 2);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html):

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(EnumVariantCount)]
pub fn derive_enum_variant_count(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let syn_item: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let len = match syn_item.data {
        syn::Data::Enum(enum_item) => enum_item.variants.len(),
        _ => panic!("EnumVariantCount only works on Enums"),
    };
    let expanded = quote! {
    const LENGTH: usize = #len;
        };
    expanded.into()
}
```

It is left as an excercise to the reader to ensure that this derive macro can be used multiple times within the same module.

To use the macro, just attach `#[derive(EnumVariantCount)]` to your enum. There should now be a global constant named `LENGTH`.

Comment: Awesome! But I think the proper way (right now) to handle erorrs, such as a non-enum body is to panic. I very much like [this post](https://cbreeden.github.io/Macros11/) to learn Macros 1.1.

Comment: Why would we panic on a non-enum? There's no difference between a single variant enum and a tuple struct.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't think about it enough. But at least *I* would expect that attaching `#[derive(EnumVariantCount)]` to a struct definition results in a compile time error.

Comment: Right... the naming is unfortunate. It's probably a mistake if it's added to a struct.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative (maybe this is newer since the original answer) you can use the [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum) crate and use the EnumCount macro.  Here is their [example](https://docs.rs/strum/0.24.0/strum/derive.EnumCount.html):

```
use strum::{EnumCount, IntoEnumIterator};
use strum_macros::{EnumCount as EnumCountMacro, EnumIter};

#[derive(Debug, EnumCountMacro, EnumIter)]
enum Week {
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
}

assert_eq!(7, Week::COUNT);
assert_eq!(Week::iter().count(), Week::COUNT);
```