# Is there a way to test macros in rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, macros

I'm trying to get started with TDD in Rust and I need to write a macro, which returns the number of variants in an enum. My implementation is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638362/5625089):

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(EnumVariantCount)]
pub fn derive_enum_variant_count(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let syn_item: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let len = match syn_item.data {
        syn::Data::Enum(enum_item) => enum_item.variants.len(),
        _ => panic!("EnumVariantCount only works on Enums"),
    };
    let expanded = quote! {
    const LENGTH: usize = #len;
        };
    expanded.into()
}
```

So first I want to write a test to check if this macro only works on an enum. How would this even work? Can I somehow check if a file compiles in a unit test? Is there some documentation on testing rust macros that I overlooked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`trybuild`](https://docs.rs/trybuild/1.0.25/trybuild/) crate has been created specifically for this: it compiles a test file and then checks for expected compile-time errors.

Comment: Also [`macrotest`](https://github.com/eupn/macrotest) is a similar alternative.

Comment: The answer (`trybuild`) doesn't resolve the question in my case, as I also want to validate the expansion matches my expectations:

"Pass tests are considered to succeed if they compile successfully and have a main function that does not panic when the compiled binary is executed." ([Trybuild docs](https://docs.rs/trybuild/1.0.25/trybuild/#pass-tests))

`macrotest`, mentioned in the comment above, does actually validate that the expansion meets expectations