# How to get all the variants of an enum in a Vec<T> with a proc-macro?

Tags: rust, enums

I am wondering how to implement a method for any enum that will return all variants in a `Vec<T>` or some kind of collection type. Something like:

```
pub enum MyEnum {
    EnumVariant1
    EnumVariant2
    ...
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn values(&self) -> Vec<MyEnum> {
        // do Rust stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [In Rust, is there a way to iterate through the values of an enum?](/q/21371534/2189130) or were you specifically asking about how to write the macro and not just the end goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can use a proc macro which makes it generic (inspired by [How to get the number of elements (variants) in an enum as a constant value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637978/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-variants-in-an-enum-as-a-constant-value)):

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(AllVariants)]
pub fn derive_all_variants(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let syn_item: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let variants = match syn_item.data {
        syn::Data::Enum(enum_item) => {
            enum_item.variants.into_iter().map(|v| v.ident)
        }
        _ => panic!("AllVariants only works on enums"),
    };
    let enum_name = syn_item.ident;

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl #enum_name {
            pub fn all_variants() -> &'static[#enum_name] {
                &[ #(#enum_name::#variants),* ]
            }
        }
    };
    expanded.into()
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
use all_variants::AllVariants;

#[derive(AllVariants, Debug)]
enum Direction {
    Left,
    Top,
    Right,
    Bottom,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Direction::all_variants());
}
```

Output:

```
[Left, Top, Right, Bottom]
```

But as @Denys Séguret wrote in a previous comment, it's lot more work:

- proc macros has to reside in their own crate (if you want to publish your work on crates.io, the proc macro crate has to be published as well);
- it requires `syn` and `quote` crates in the proc macro (if don't want to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: I didn't notice this answer until now, but this one should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

There's no smart and standard solution.

An obvious one is to declare the array yourself, by repeating the variants:

```rust
static VARIANTS: &[MyEnum] = &[
    MyEnum::EnumVariant1,
    MyEnum::EnumVariant2,
];
```

This is a reasonable solution. When your code evolve, it's frequent you discover you don't want *all* variants in your static array. Or that you need several arrays.

Alternatively, if there are many elements or several enums, you may create a macro for this purpose:

```rust
macro_rules! make_enum {
    (
        $name:ident $array:ident {
            $( $variant:ident, )*
        }
    ) => {
        pub enum $name {
            $( $variant, )*
        }
        static $array: &[$name] = &[
            $( $name::$variant, )*
        ];
    }
}

make_enum! (MyEnum VARIANTS {
    EnumVariant1,
    EnumVariant2,
});
```

This `make_enum!` macro call would create both the enum and a static array called `VARIANTS`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. 
In my code, I used to make the first aproach you've wrote, but I was wondering if there is a way to implement the feature on a generic way throught trait impl

Comment: No, this can't be done with generics. The macro is simple enough. You may implement a similar solution with a derive macro but it's a lot more work, implies other crates, and makes it difficult to adapt to different situations so I'd recommend the "simple" macro_rules.

Comment: Yes, you're completly right. And I like you're approach.
Thanks for share your knowledge!

Comment: [do not upvote, this comment is useless] Thanks (again) Denys :D It's been a while. I didn't expect to see answers from you when I was looking for Rust related stuff. Hope we'll see more and more rustaceans from Lyon ;) Take care